# AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().outputVolume Not Returning Correct Volume Consistently

Tags: ios, swift, avaudiosession

With the following code, I get the output volume, but it is really inconsistent - sometime it gives the same values, sometimes it is a volume change behind, despite the system volume actually changing correctly.

Any way to get this to output correct values every time?

```
func viewDidLoad() {
...

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(volumeDidChange), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "AVSystemController_SystemVolumeDidChangeNotification"), object: nil)
...

}


func volumeDidChange() {
   print("VOLUME CHANGING", AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().outputVolume)

// output while changing the volume with hardware buttons
VOLUME CHANGING 0.0625
VOLUME CHANGING 0.0625
VOLUME CHANGING 0.125
VOLUME CHANGING 0.1875
VOLUME CHANGING 0.25
VOLUME CHANGING 0.375
VOLUME CHANGING 0.375
VOLUME CHANGING 0.4375
VOLUME CHANGING 0.5
VOLUME CHANGING 0.5625
VOLUME CHANGING 0.625
VOLUME CHANGING 0.6875
VOLUME CHANGING 0.75
VOLUME CHANGING 0.8125
VOLUME CHANGING 0.875
VOLUME CHANGING 0.75
VOLUME CHANGING 0.6875
VOLUME CHANGING 0.625
VOLUME CHANGING 0.625
VOLUME CHANGING 0.5625
VOLUME CHANGING 0.5
VOLUME CHANGING 0.4375
VOLUME CHANGING 0.375
VOLUME CHANGING 0.3125
VOLUME CHANGING 0.375
VOLUME CHANGING 0.4375
VOLUME CHANGING 0.4375
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
import AVFoundation
import MediaPlayer

//MARK: Did Load
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    /// Volume View
    let volumeView = MPVolumeView(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 100))
    volumeView.isHidden = false
    volumeView.alpha = 0.01
    view.addSubview(volumeView)

    /// Notification Observer
     NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.volumeDidChange(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "AVSystemController_SystemVolumeDidChangeNotification"), object: nil)
}

@objc func volumeDidChange(notification: NSNotification) {
    //print("VOLUME CHANGING", AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().outputVolume)

    let volume = notification.userInfo!["AVSystemController_AudioVolumeNotificationParameter"] as! Float
    print("Device Volume:\(volume)")
}
```

**Your current output** - Same Values getting Repeated

[image]

**Required Output**

[image]

Comment: Thanks! - getting the value from the notification itself did the trick! Guess it takes a bit for the system to actually put the correct value in the right places (because the volume slider and outputvolume almost never match when the notification is sent)

Comment: Welcome , hope this solve your query and if yes, You can close this thread by accepting answer

Answer (score 3):

## Updated for Swift 4.2

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    
    do {
        try session.setActive(true)
    } catch {
        print("error in getting volume")
    }
    
    if session.outputVolume < 1.0 {
        volumeButton = 0
    } else {
        volumeButton = 1
    }
    
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.volumeDidChange(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "AVSystemController_SystemVolumeDidChangeNotification"), object: nil)
}

@objc func volumeDidChange(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let volume = notification.userInfo?["AVSystemController_AudioVolumeNotificationParameter"] as? Float{
        print("Device Volume:\(volume)")
    } else{
        print("Error while reading value...")
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi! It doesn't work for me in iOS 14.2. Observer does not call the selector func. Can anybody help with this?